# OpenTok TokBox - comparing opentok-react-native and Web SDK

Tags: opentok

where can I find detailed comparisons of the trade-offs in using one or the other?

I presume react native will use the iOS and Android SDKs which will yield better operability, performance, support, and features. Is this true? Where can I find documentation describing this?

Answer (score 0):

As the heavy lifting is done natively by the browsers when using the OpenTok JS SDK, I would not expect much of a performance difference between the two.

I would consider the target audience and what mix of technologies you are using to build your application to be the important question here.

If your application's primary use-case is for mobile users, perhaps going react-native or even native is probably the way to go.

If your application is primarily web-based and you expect the target audience does not wish to install an app for it, then the OpenTok JS SDK might be the better solution.